# Stripe checkout session working on localhost, but not with live histinger nodejs

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a react js eccomerce web with Stripe Session payment, the session works fine on localhost but when i create a build and run the website hosted by Hostinger. It doesn't work .Cart.js:84 Error: No session ID received from the server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to visit your Stripe Dashboard and check the [logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs) to find out whether the checkout session was created successfully.